# lxml: Element is not a child of this node

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to change the value of title within the following html document:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title id="title"></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote the following python script which uses lxml, in order to accomplish the task:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
from lxml.html import builder as E

html = fromstring(open('./index.html').read())
html.replace(html.get_element_by_id('title'), E.TITLE('TEST'))
```

But after running the script, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.

What's supposed to cause this error? Thank you.

Comment: `<title>` is child of `<head`, the first Parameter of `.replace(...` has to be the Parent of  `<title>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'title' tag is a child of the 'head' node. In your code you use `replace` on the 'html' node, which has no 'title' elements (not directly), hence the `ValueError`.

You can get the desired results if you use `replace` on the 'head' node.

```
html.find('head').replace(html.get_element_by_id('title'), E.TITLE('TEST'))
```

Comment: Perfect, I understood. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Woah, this is really tricky. By your inspiration, I ended up using `old_ele.getparent().replace(old_ele, new_ele)`